# Why Flutter hybrid app does not start? I have used webview and google mobad that should show an ad when the app started

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, admob, hybrid-mobile-app

I am about to create an app using webview in flutter language and I want to show open app in mobad when the app opened or started.

The code you provided is written in Dart programming language. It initializes an instance of the "AppOpenAdManager" class and calls the "loadAd" method on it. Then, it initializes an instance of the "AppLifecycleReactor" class and passes the "appOpenAdManager" instance to its constructor.

The purpose of this code is to load and manage an advertisement using the "AppOpenAdManager" class, and to monitor the lifecycle events of the app using the "AppLifecycleReactor" class.

I am very new to flutter, thank you for helping me.

here's main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:factorial/app_open_ad_manager.dart';
import 'app_lifecycle_reactor.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();

  late AppLifecycleReactor _appLifecycleReactor;
  AppOpenAdManager appOpenAdManager = AppOpenAdManager()..loadAd();
  _appLifecycleReactor =
      AppLifecycleReactor(appOpenAdManager: appOpenAdManager);

  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: WebViewApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class WebViewApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebViewApp> createState() => _WebViewAppState();
}

class _WebViewAppState extends State<WebViewApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  late final WebViewController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..loadRequest(
        Uri.parse('https://example.com'),
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WebViewWidget(
        controller: controller,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here's app_open_ad_manager.dart

```
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

class AppOpenAdManager {
  String adUnitId = Platform.isAndroid
      ? 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3419835294'
      : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5662855259';

  AppOpenAd? _appOpenAd;
  bool _isShowingAd = false;

  void loadAd() {
    AppOpenAd.load(
      adUnitId: adUnitId,
      orientation: AppOpenAd.orientationPortrait,
      request: AdRequest(),
      adLoadCallback: AppOpenAdLoadCallback(
        onAdLoaded: (ad) {
          _appOpenAd = ad;
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (error) {
          print('AppOpenAd failed to load: $error');
          // Handle the error.
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void showAdIfAvailable() {
    if (!isAdAvailable) {
      print('Tried to show ad before available.');
      loadAd();
      return;
    }
    if (_isShowingAd) {
      print('Tried to show ad while already showing an ad.');
      return;
    }
    // Set the fullScreenContentCallback and show the ad.
    _appOpenAd!.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
      onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (ad) {
        _isShowingAd = true;
        print('$ad onAdShowedFullScreenContent');
      },
      onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (ad, error) {
        print('$ad onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: $error');
        _isShowingAd = false;
        ad.dispose();
        _appOpenAd = null;
      },
      onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (ad) {
        print('$ad onAdDismissedFullScreenContent');
        _isShowingAd = false;
        ad.dispose();
        _appOpenAd = null;
        loadAd();
      },
    );
  }

  /// Whether an ad is available to be shown.
  bool get isAdAvailable {
    return _appOpenAd != null;
  }
}
```

and here's

```
import 'app_open_ad_manager.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

/// Listens for app foreground events and shows app open ads.
class AppLifecycleReactor {
  final AppOpenAdManager appOpenAdManager;

  AppLifecycleReactor({required this.appOpenAdManager});

  void listenToAppStateChanges() {
    AppStateEventNotifier.startListening();
    AppStateEventNotifier.appStateStream
        .forEach((state) => _onAppStateChanged(state));
  }

  void _onAppStateChanged(AppState appState) {
    // Try to show an app open ad if the app is being resumed and
    // we're not already showing an app open ad.
    if (appState == AppState.foreground) {
      appOpenAdManager.showAdIfAvailable();
    }
  }
}
```

I was following this [Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/app-open) and I got all the codes there.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are missing 2 things:

First one after initialise AppLifecycleReactor

```
_appLifecycleReactor =
      AppLifecycleReactor(appOpenAdManager: appOpenAdManager);
```

you have to start listening app state changes adding this line

```
_appLifecycleReactor.listenToAppStateChanges();
```

And the second after create fullScreenContentCallback you have to add

```
    _appOpenAd!.show();
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/flutter/app-open